# RegEx Matching only the first two digits in a year

Tags: regex

I am trying to match only the first two digits in a year so that I may replace then with FY.

For example: I would like 2022 to become FY22.

The following

```
\d+
```

Has replaced everything and

```
\d+{2}
```

Has left me with FYFY.

Any help would be treat.

This will be translated into an Alteryx tool.

THank you in advance.

Comment: Match `\b\d{2}(\d{2})\b` and replace with `FY$1`

Comment: Assuming your regex engine supports *positive lookaheads*, match `\b\d{2}(?=\d{2}\b)` and replace the match with `'FY'`. The positive lookahead, `(?=\d{2}\b)`, asserts that the match is followed by two digits followed by a word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your patterns:

- Using `\d+` matches 1 or more digits which is too broad for a year match
- Using `\d+{2}` is not a valid expression, as the quantifier `+` is [not quantifiable](https://regex101.com/r/FADXnm/1) by `{2}`

If you want to narrow down the matching for a year to not just match any 4 digits, you could make the match a bit more specific:

```
\b(?:19|20)(\d\d)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:19|20)` Match either 19 or 20
- `(\d\d)` Capture 2 digits in group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

And replace using the capture group `$1`

```
FY$1
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l9I5hD/1).

---

Reading the page about the [alteryx RegEx Tool](https://help.alteryx.com/2018.2/RegEx.htm?Highlight=regex), it uses Boost RegEx.

In that case you can also use a lookahead variant:

```
\b(?:19|20)(?=\d\d\b)
```

And replace with just `FY`

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeoVKD/1).